# How to get the groupby keys with a loop?

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to do some somewhat complicated processing for each group after grouping.
in `pandas`, it can be writed as follows:

```py
for i,g in df.groupby(['id','sid']):
    pass
```

While in polars, the `groups` function returns a DataFrame, But this cannot be conveniently applied to for loops.

Comment: `df.groupby(['id','sid']).groups.keys()` this will give list of keys, is this you are asking

Comment: `df.groupby().apply()` is a *very* convenient way to do whatever you think you need a for loop for. I can almost guarantee that a for loop is not the best approach...

Comment: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'keys' @
Vignesh is your suggestion is about polars?

Comment: I try to rewrite with apply in `pandas` but it can not stop by condition(when in for loop, I can count the time of iteration and stop it for testing the performance of code ), my data has 1 million and use a subset of data to test the performance is not suitable for the indicator which I  need to construct, so I want to write it with `pandas` first  then rewrite it by `polars`.@BeRT2me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use partition by. This would yield a `dictionary` where the `groupby` keys map to the partitioned `DataFrames`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "groups": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "values": pl.arange(0, 5, eager=True)
})

part_dfs = df.partition_by("groups", as_dict=True)

print(part_dfs)
```

```
{1: shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬────────┐
│ groups ┆ values │
│ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 1      │
└────────┴────────┘,
 2: shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬────────┐
│ groups ┆ values │
│ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪════════╡
│ 2      ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 3      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 4      │
└────────┴────────┘}
```